# Compare a row of a dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    price        trend  decreasing  increasing  condition_decreasing
    0   7610.4  no trend    0.0     False       
    1   7610.4  no trend    0.0     False       
    2   7610.4  no trend    0.0     False       
    3   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  True        
    4   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
    5   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
    6   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
    7   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
    8   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
    9   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
    10  7610.3  no trend    0.0     True        
    11  7610.3  no trend    0.0     False       
    12  7613.9  no trend    0.0     False   
    13  7613.9  no trend    0.0     False
    14  7613.4  no trend    0.0     False
    15  7613    decreasing  7613    True    
    16  7612    decreasing  7612    False 
    17  7612    decreasing  7612    False
    18  7612    no trend    7612    True
```

What I need to do basically is when the column `trend` goes from `no trend` to `decreasing` is to take that value from the column `price` and compare it with the value of the column `price` when the column trend goes from `decreasing` to `no trend`. So in the example above it would be to compared the value 7610.4 from row 3 with the value 7610.3 from row 10.

I tried to add a column which indicates when the column trend changes, using the following code:
`condition_decreasing = (data['trend'] != data['trend'].shift(1))`

But then after I do not know how to iterate on the dataframe in a loop and compare the two prices... any idea? thanks for the help!

The expected output would be a dataframe like that:

```
price    trend  decreasing  increasing  condition_decreasing output
0   7610.4  no trend    0.0     False       
1   7610.4  no trend    0.0     False       
2   7610.4  no trend    0.0     False       
3   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  True        
4   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
5   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
6   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
7   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
8   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
9   7610.4  decreasing  7610.4  False       
10  7610.3  no trend    0.0     True        -0.1
11  7610.3  no trend    0.0     False       
12  7613.9  no trend    0.0     False 
13  7613.9  no trend    0.0     False
14  7613.4  no trend    0.0     False
15  7613    decreasing  7613    True    
16  7612    decreasing  7612    False 
17  7612    decreasing  7612    False
18  7612    no trend    7612    True        -1
```

So basically a column with the difference of the two prices `7610.3 - 7610.4`

Comment: provide expected output

Comment: Yes, I added a dataframe with what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) after calculating the difference:

```
m=data['trend'].ne( data['trend'].shift()
                                 .fillna(data['trend']) )
data['output']=( data.loc[m,'price'].diff()
                     .reindex(data.index)
                     .where(data['trend'].eq('no trend')) )
                    #.where(data['trend'].ne('decreasing'))  )
                    #.where(data['trend'].str.replace(' ','').eq('notrend')) )

print(data)

# m is your condition_decreasing column

#data['output']=( data.loc[data['condition_decreasing'],'price']
#                     .diff()
#                     .reindex(data.index)
#                     .where(data['trend'].eq('no trend')) )
```

**Output**

```
     price            trend  decreasing_increasing  output
0   7610.4         no trend                    0.0     NaN
1   7610.4         no trend                    0.0     NaN
2   7610.4         no trend                    0.0     NaN
3   7610.4       decreasing                 7610.4     NaN
4   7610.4       decreasing                 7610.4     NaN
5   7610.4       decreasing                 7610.4     NaN
6   7610.4       decreasing                 7610.4     NaN
7   7610.4       decreasing                 7610.4     NaN
8   7610.4       decreasing                 7610.4     NaN
9   7610.4       decreasing                 7610.4     NaN
10  7610.3         no trend                    0.0    -0.1
11  7610.3         no trend                    0.0     NaN
12  7613.9         no trend                    0.0     NaN
```

Comment: It works very well, but the only issue that I have is that it compares also the two prices between a decreasing "sequence" and the next "sequence" of decreasing.

Comment: Could you show a more detailed example of what to do?

Comment: I modified my example to explain you. So basically your code works but it also gives the difference between the price of line 10 and line 15 (2.7), so between two decreasing "sequence" which I do not need.

Comment: I have updated the solution for it.please, try now. Make sure that in your `trend` column the `no trend` values ​​do not contain additional spaces. Otherwise you could use: `.where (data ['trend']. ne ('drecreasing'))` or `mask`instead `where`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

price = [7610.3, 7610.3, 7610.4, 7610.4, 7610.4, 7610.4, 7610.3, 7610.3, 7610.9]

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': price})
df['diff'] = df['price'].diff()
conditions = [
    (df['diff'] == 0),
    (df['diff'] > 0),
    (df['diff'] < 0)]
choices = ['no trend', 'increasing', 'decreasing']
df['trend'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = None)
print(df)

    price  diff       trend
0  7610.3   NaN        None
1  7610.3   0.0    no trend
2  7610.4   0.1  increasing
3  7610.4   0.0    no trend
4  7610.4   0.0    no trend
5  7610.4   0.0    no trend
6  7610.3  -0.1  decreasing
7  7610.3   0.0    no trend
8  7610.9   0.6  increasing
```

Comment: I think he wants to get the output column

Comment: I improved the answer based on your comment, thanks